# Matlab: Efficient right shift computation

Tags: matlab

I want to know if there is an efficient way to perform a right shift operation in MATLAB.  I have a number X thats belongs to Z+, and I want to divide this number by the closed power of 2.

for example: If X = 7169440, then the closed power of 2 will be 2^23.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
    X/pow2(2,round(log2(X)))
```

Comment: What about `X/pow2(nextpow2(X)-1)`? I think this is rather some sort of generale mathematics problem - as you'd need to find some form to express this as easiest as possible. **EDIT**: Maybe you'll want to write this part of your code in C and compile it for MATLAB (use mexFunctions). Shouldn't be too hard and you could do all the other stuff (matrix handling or whatever you are doing else in your code) within MATLAB.

Comment: thanks,  I tried your suggestion and it is almost the same in terms of computation time. I' ll try using mexFunctions and i'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never benchmarked this, but an ordinary bitshift operation should be quite efficient,

```
a = [16,32]
bitshift(a,-1)
bitshift(a,1)
```

Comment: thanks, and I found that there is also a function called FI used to contruct fixed-point numeric object. So I did         bitshift( fi(X), -nextpow2(X) )